# using UIImagepickerController cameraoverlayview to take picture?

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiimagepickercontroller

i am using UIImagepickerController to take pictures from camera..i am using my own view over the camera view by using the cameraoverlayview property...i want to take a picture from camera when user clicks on a button in my custom view...i am using the following code

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {

imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];   
    imagePickerController.showsCameraControls=NO;

imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView = self.customView;

}

- (IBAction) takePicture
{
    [imagePickerController takePicture];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    imageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

but when i run this code it gives me error

> ERROR: FigCreateCGImageFromJPEG returned -12905. Input (null) was 773625 bytes.

and i also get warnings for memory use level 2 and then level 1

and no image is displayed in the imageView.. can anyone help me what i might be doing wrong??
btw i am using iPhone 3G with iOS4.1 installed on it

Comment: Not sure, but look into UIImage vs UIImageView. I suspect that it may have to do with your `[info objectforKey: ... ]` call.

Comment: actually didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo is not even getting called.. i already included the delegate for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` is a symbol (an `NSString *` constant) and you can't assume its value. Use as is, without quotes. Other than that, if you properly retain and create both the picker and the image view, it should work.